# FreeBSD Clonezilla Not Restoring

Tags: freebsd, clonezilla

I made a backup with Clonezilla of my FreeBSD install. I used the default options for doing a disk image. It backed up 3 partitions into the image. The boot, the root and I forget the third.

When making the backup, I had Clonezilla verify the backup was restorable. When I go to restore the backup, it completes, but upon reboot there is no boot table. The system doesn't know how to proceed.

I'm now going through advanced restore options to see if I can get the boot loader to restore. Nothing I do seems to restore the boot loader. It restores the partitions, and that's it.

Does Clonezilla not work with FreeBSD in terms of restoring the boot loader? Did I need to do an expert backup to select options when backing up the FreeBSD system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around and testing I was able to get it working with the -j1 option in the expert settings.

```
-j1, --dump-mbr-in-the-end Use dd to dump the MBR (total 512 bytes, i.e. 446 bytes (executable code area) + 64 bytes (table of primary partitions) + 2 bytes (MBR signature; # 0xAA55) = 512 bytes) after disk image was restored. This is an insurance for some hard drive has different numbers of cylinder, head and sector between image was saved and restored.
```