# Restored encrypted LUKS drive with CloneZilla makes system non-bootable

Tags: linux, boot, grub, luks, clonezilla

As the title says, I've made a backup of my system before sending my laptop for tech repairs, my system was encrypted and I used CloneZilla's beginner mode so as to not mess anything up. I received my computer today and I tried to restore the image made by CloneZilla on the machine. Everything looked like it worked, but when I try to boot the machine by selecting the main drive on the boot menu, nothing happens. It juste brings me back to the BIOS boot menu. I am not greeted with any Grub or LUKS decrypt screen. I'm at a loss of ideas for what to try next, any help is greatly appreciated.

I've also tried this: [FreeBSD Clonezilla Not Restoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241241/freebsd-clonezilla-not-restoring)

and

Rescatux, but for reasons which i attribute to my drive being encrypted, it cannot fix any problem and only asks to install GRUB on external drives.

Edit to answer questions:
I am using EndeavourOS, an Arch Linux fork,
I cloned the entire disk and verified it. Also, I restored it on the exact same drive, therefore image vs drive sizes isn't an issue. Also, after unencrypting the partitions once in a live USB, I do seem to have access to the partitions themselves.

Perhaps it is an issue with GRUB not having been reinstalled when cloning?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Did you backup and restore only a single partition or the whole disk? Which distribution are you using? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I would sort out a Live Linux USB and inspect the drive to see what's there, it's impossible to know from your question what's happened or how to fix it.  An Ubuntu install disk will work as a Live USB (just select "try ubuntu" after booting it).

Comment: 1. Did you test the backup image before you sent the laptop for tech repairs? In that case you can be sure that you managed to create a restorable image, and with some patience you will be able to restore a working system; 2. Is the target drive at least as big as the original drive (not one single byte smaller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that somehow my Secure Boot was enabled in my BIOS. Turning it off solved my entire problem. Turns out the repair shop reset some settings in the BIOS...

In brief, to solve the problem, go into BIOS and disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Linux works quite nicely with UEFI Secure Boot if you have enough patience: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Using_your_own_keys https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#MOK_-_Machine_Owner_Key https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot